# Getting NoClassDefFoundError for jetty server while starting Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to start spring boot application. Getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedJetty.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory]: Factory method 'jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at com.filinv.rtl.ei.ao.app.Application.main(Application.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedJetty.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory]: Factory method 'jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext
```

mvn dependency:tree

```
*+- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.0.0-milestone1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:jar:3.0.0-milestone1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:compile*
```

Comment: Got it fixed by excluding cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty jars from the classpath causing version mismatch.

Answer (score 3):

You are hitting [a bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4089) in Spring Boot where it tries to auto-configure Jetty even though a required part of it isn't on the classpath. The bug was fixed in Spring Boot 1.2.7.RELEASE. You haven't said what version you're using, but I assume that it's earlier than that. Upgrading to an up-to-date version should fix your problem. At the time of writing the latest version is 1.3.3.RELEASE.

Comment: I am using 1.3.6 and still got this.

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop That's probably best addressed in a new question